# Scrapy: merge items from different sites

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to merge items where I get items from site A and items from site B.

A items and B items share some fields which allow me to correlate items. Otherwise, each have fields which are unique to A or B.

I want to merge these items based on correlation, creating items containing

- the shared fields,
- the fields unique to A, and
- the fields unique to B.

Items which are unique to A or B should pass through unchanged.

I *cannot* assume:

- items on A and B are in same order
- each A item has a corresponding B item
- each B item has a corresponding A item

How would I do that in Scrapy? Does it make sense to do in Scrapy or better in a postprocessing step?

**Thoughts on implementation:**

Since I cannot assume order, I would need a temp store. I am looking at <1000 items, so in-memory temp storage seems feasible.

Pseudocode:

```
A_items = list() # in-memory temp storage

for A_item in A_site:
    A_items.append(A_item)

for B_item in B_site:
    for A_item in A_items:
        if is_correlated(A_item, B_item):
            AB_item = merge(A_item, B_item)
            A_items.remove(A_item)
            yield AB_item
        else:
            yield B_item # B_item without A_item

# remaining A_items, for which we did not find a B_item
for A_item in A_items:
    yield A_item
```

Where to put this logic?

- I cannot use an item pipeline because I need to yield several items
  for emptying the temp storage. I understand an item pipeline can
  return exactly zero or one item but not more.
- I could build a spider which knows how to scrape both sites. I could
  put the logic into the spider.
- I couuld build a custom extractor and put the logic there.

Comment: I would do this separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sorta use case I think post processing is the easiest, most straightforward and reliable path. Will also make things easier if you have to do any additional post processing / aggregation later on.

- You could in theory have your pipeline just buffer the items and regularly flush them into whatever storage you are using directly. But the thing is, in order for a pipeline/middleware to see items yielded across multiple spiders you would have to design them to use some sort of a shared storage since scrapy engine is a single spider only.
- One spider solution is an okay option I think but not the most elegant, plus as far as I know there's no straightforward way to yield items after spider has finished so that would have to be implemented as an additional hack.